# Cannot append the data into xml file using Django and Python

Tags: python, xml, django

I am trying to append all my post data into xml file but it always overwrite. Here is my code:

```
def some(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        location_name = request.POST.get('lname')
        rname = request.POST.get('rname')
        seat = request.POST.get('seat')
        projector = request.POST.get('projector')
        video = request.POST.get('video')
        root = ET.Element("roomlist")
        doc = ET.SubElement(root, "locationname", name=location_name)
        doc1 = ET.SubElement(doc, "roomid", name="1234")
        ET.SubElement(doc1, "roomname", name=rname).text = rname
        ET.SubElement(doc1, "noseats", name=seat).text = seat
        ET.SubElement(doc1, "projectorscreen", name=projector).text = projector
        ET.SubElement(doc1, "videoconf", name=video).text = video
        tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
        tree.write("filename.xml")
    return render(request, 'booking/bmr.html', {})
```

Here I need when user will submit the form all data will append into the existing XML file but in my case its overwriting every time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your data and append to the file :

```
root = tree.getroot()    
xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, 'utf-8', method='xml')
with open("filename.xml", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(xmlstr)
```

So what i do is creating the tree (your code) and convert to string (`tostring()`) and just append this string to a file :)

Comment: I did as per you but its throwing this `NameError at /some/
global name 'ElementTree' is not defined
` error.

Comment: I am using this `import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET` one

Comment: so use `ET.fromstring` instead of `ElementTree.tostring`

Comment: I did but its throwing this `TypeError at /some/
XML() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'` error.

Comment: i've edited my answer for your need using cElementTree

Comment: Yes it started working. Thank you. Can you help me for one more functionality.?

Comment: i think you need to create another question and make this resolved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146769/discussion-between-satya-and-maximek).